# Comma after an adverb that starts a sentence

Tags: adverbs, commas

> When should a comma be placed after the adverb that starts the sentence?

When should there be a comma when adverbs like [well](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well), [seemingly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seemingly), [apparently](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/apparently), [supposedly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supposedly), [definitely](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/definitely), [surely](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/surely), [obviously](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obviously), [conclusively](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conclusively), [possibly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/possibly), [indeed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indeed), [actually](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/actually), [naturally](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/naturally) and others start a sentence?

- **Seemingly,** she's gone to live with another man.
- **Apparently** it's going to rain today.
- **Supposedly,** she never spoke to him again.
- **Well,** the tickets are supposedly in the mail.
- **Surely** you don't expect me to believe that?
- **Obviously** the school cannot function without teachers.
- **Indeed,** it could be the worst environmental disaster in Europe this century.
- **Actually,** Gavin, it was Tuesday of last week, not Wednesday.
- **Naturally** we want to see as few job losses in the industry as possible.

As you can see some adverbs are followed by a comma while others are not.

Comment: They all *could* have one, except "surely". The question is thus which ones can or even prefer to drop it.

Comment: Who requires it?  Do you really consider **well** an adverb there?  Isn't it just a kind of discourse marker?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I thought it was an interjection at first.

Comment: You could dispense with commas after all but **well** and **actually**. Some editor might insist you put them back. The house always wins.

Comment: The use of the comma is a matter of style. There are no rules when it comes to style. Use them wherever you might take a breath in speaking a sentence aloud.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I thought there was a rule concerning commas after adverbs when they start a sentence. I almost always see a comma after **actually** but never after **surely**. Sometimes a comma after **apparently** is placed and sometimes not.

Comment: That's because there is no _rule_ "governing" the comma's usage. The concept of "rules" is inimical to many things about English grammar and usage. The quest for "rules" is often misguided. There is no-one to enforce such "rules", if they existed.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Could it be the difference between an adverb being the actual adverb or it being the interjection instead?

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the words that you have written in **bold** are a type of **adverbial** (a type of adverb) which is called an **disjunct**. (whether they are all disjuncts could be argued.).

.Disjuncts allow the speaker/writer to **influence** the hearer or reader..  They represent the speaker's attitude about what he is going to say.

Here are some examples where the adjunct is written in bold:

**Naturally**, you are going to go you. = the speaker is certain you will go.

**Obviously**,I agree with the president. = Its obvious that the speaker will agree.

**Of course**, she is late.  = I think it is to be expected.

**Regrettably**, he didn't attend the meeting.=  I think its sad or too bad that he didn't come.

**Surely,** you are going to go to school today. = a strong sense of persuasion.

**Frankly**, I couldn't care less about comma rules. = the speaker really doesn't care.

In each case we use a comma to separate the emotion or attitude of the speaker from the rest of the sentence. Some authorities believe that a comma should be used if the disjunct doesn't flow with the rest of the sentence and in most cases  disjuncts are separated by a comma.

There are no hard and fast rules about comma use. and convention plays a role in determining some rules. You learn from experience and even English teachers can get it wrong.

Source Grammar 33 manual U of Saskatchewan, Longman's Dictionary, Guide to Grammar Writing by Charles Darling.